# Firebase realtime database crashes on Amazon Kindle Fire devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kindle-fire

I'm getting the following error when trying to access the realtime database from Google Firebase on an Amazon Kindle Fire device.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqi$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

I believe this is because Google Play services is missing. Does this mean that Firebase won't work on Kindle Fire devices?

They both have "Fire" in their names, does that count for nothing!?

EDIT:

I think it may be related to Proguard. I am also getting this error in my log files.

> Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.firebase_database.ModuleDescriptor"
>   on path

Answer (score 6):

From Firebase Android setup documentation (`https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites`):

> Prerequisites
>
> A device running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or newer, and Google Play
>   services 9.0.1 or newer

So Firebase will not work on Kindle Fire devices without Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google fixed it. I upgraded Firebase and Google Play Services from 9.0.0 to 9.0.1 and the problem went away. Firebase database does work with the Kindle Fire.

**EDIT:**

It was not the play services version. It was because I had Proguard disabled. I need to investigate further but now I know it's possible.

Comment: I would love to hear some followup on this, according to the documentation, this should not work...

Comment: How are you managing to run Google Play Services on your Kindle Fire? Would love to know more.

Comment: @theJosh Can you please share the details that how you managed to run Google play services on Kindle Fire? If possible please share your sample code. Also, mention if you have rooted your kindle or side loaded play services onto it. Thanks.

Comment: @Perry I didn't run Play Services on Kindle. That version of Firebase did not require it. Probally because I wasn't using authentication.

Comment: @theJosh Thanks, Did you use Firebase REST API's on your kindle to access Firebase Realtime Database?

Comment: @Perry I used the normal Android sdk. This was a while back though. We have given up on Kindle support  since then. Which was probably why Google set it up like that.